# After resuming the activity add to favorite marks are not visible

Tags: android, kotlin

I am added add to favorites button to my recyclerview's item but after going to previous activity and coming back to this activity my all add to Favourites marks are getting invisible.

How to restore all these marked favorites while resuming the activity?

This is my member's activity on which I have applied recyclerview

```
class MembersActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, View.OnClickListener {


    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var btnSort: Button
    lateinit var adapter: DataAdapter
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    var members: List<Member> = ArrayList()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_members)
        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        btnSort = findViewById(R.id.btn_sort)
        btnSort.setOnClickListener(this)
        members= intent.getSerializableExtra("MEMBER_LIST") as List<Member>
        Log.v("MemberActivity",""+members);

        btnSort = findViewById(R.id.btn_sort)
        btnSort.setOnClickListener(this)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.adapter=
            MemberAdapter(members, this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

    }



    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitems, menu)
        val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionsearch)
        val searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem) as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }


    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
       return false;
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        val newText=newText!!.toLowerCase();
        var newDataList : MutableList<Member> = ArrayList()

        for(responseItem in members){
            val firstName=responseItem.name.first.toLowerCase()
            val lastName=responseItem.name.last.toLowerCase()

            if(firstName.contains(newText) || lastName.contains(newText)){
                Log.v("LastName",""+lastName)
                newDataList.add(responseItem)
            }
        }

        recyclerView.adapter=
            MemberAdapter(newDataList, this)
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

       return true;
    }




     fun savestate(id:String,isFavourite: Boolean) {
        val aSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val aSharedPreferencesEdit = aSharedPreferences.edit()
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.putBoolean(id, isFavourite)
        aSharedPreferencesEdit.apply()
    }

     fun readstate(id:String): Boolean {
        val asharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return asharedPreferences.getBoolean(id, false)
    }




}
```

This is my adapter class

```
class MemberAdapter(private var dataList: List<Member>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.member_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return dataList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val dataModel=dataList.get(position)
        holder.member_name.text=dataModel.name.first+" "+dataModel.name.last ;
        holder.member_age.text= dataModel.age.toString();
        holder.member_phone.text=dataModel.phone;

        holder.btn_favourite.setOnClickListener{
            if(!(context as MembersActivity).readstate(dataModel._id)){
                dataModel.isFavourite= true;
                holder.btn_favourite.setIconResource(R.drawable.star_checked)
                (context as MembersActivity).savestate(dataModel._id,true)


            }
            else{
                dataModel.isFavourite= false;
                holder.btn_favourite.setIconResource(R.drawable.star_unchecked)
                (context as MembersActivity).savestate(dataModel._id,false)

            }
        }

}


    inner class ViewHolder(itemLayoutView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemLayoutView) {
         var member_name: TextView
         var member_age: TextView
         var member_phone: TextView
         var member_email: TextView
         var btn_favourite: MaterialButton

        init {
            member_name=itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_name)
            member_age=itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_age)
            member_phone=itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_phone)
            member_email=itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_mail)
            btn_favourite=itemLayoutView.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btn_fav)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need set adapter again in `onResume`. Remove this

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        recyclerView.adapter=
            MemberAdapter(members, this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()



    }
```

Comment: After removing also the result is same

Comment: Remove it and refer @Tebfour04 answer

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to retrieve the "favorite" state in your `onBindViewHolder`. You would have the same problem even without leaving the screen if you had enough items to scroll them off the screen and back on.

You could add this to `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.btn_favourite.setIconResource(
    if ((context as MembersActivity).readstate(dataModel._id))
        R.drawable.star_checked
    else
        R.drawable.star_unchecked
)
```

But it seems odd to me that you have an array of data items, but one of the states of the items (favorite status) is not part of the model and is instead stored separately in SharedPreferences.